# Processing 2.1.1 - More than one item on the screen at once?

Tags: java, animation, processing

I'm relatively new to programming, and i'm trying to create a program that creates a purple ball where i click that moves to the right until it is off the screen, where i can have unlimited balls on the screen at once. I've made a program that does this, but i can only have one on the screen at once, if i click a second time, the first ball disappears and is replaced with a new one. Oh, and when i click a second time, the ball doesn't start where the cursor is, it starts from where the last ball was on the X-Axis.
Help please!

Here's the code:

```
int moveX, moveY;

void setup() {
  background(255);
  moveY = 200;
  moveX = 0;
  size(500,400);
}

void mouseClicked() {
moveY = mouseY;
  moveX++;

}

void draw() {
  if (moveX >= 1){
    background(255);
    fill(255, 0, 255);
    ellipse(moveX, moveY, 40, 40);
    moveX++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear and you need to be a bit more clear as to what your problem is. As far as I guess, you are keeping only one copy of the co-ordinates of the ball. How then will the other balls be created? You need to set co-ordinates for all balls. Also how do these functions work in your program?

Comment: give each ball its own coordinates

Answer (score 1):

As donfuxx suggests, giving each ball it's own coordinates.
One way to do this is using an array to store multiple values(coordinates).

To do this you need to get familiar with for loops and arrays.
They may look scary at first, but once you get the hang of them they're quite easy.
Wherever you can think of a situation where repetition is needed, you can use a for loop  to make your life easier.

For loop have the following syntax:

```
for keyword (3 elements: a start point,an end point(condition) and an increment,(separated by the ; character)
```

Let's say you want to move from a(0) to b(10) one step at a time:

```
for(int currentPos = 0 ; currentPos < 10; currentPos++){
  println("step: " + currentPos);
}
```

If you can walk, you can also skip :)

```
for(int currentPos = 0 ; currentPos < 10; currentPos+=2){
  println("step: " + currentPos);
}
```

even backwards if you want:

```
for(int currentPos = 10 ; currentPos > 0; currentPos--){
  println("step: " + currentPos);
}
```

This is very useful when traversing all sort of data(coordinates of a ball in a scene, etc.)

How do you organize your data ? You place it in a list or array.
An array contains elements of the same type and has a set length.
The syntax to declare an array is like so:

```
ObjectType[] nameOfArray;
```

and you can initialize an empty array:

```
int[] fiveNumbers = new int[5];//new keyword then the data type and length in sq.brackets
```

or you can initialize the array with values:

```
String[] words = {"ini","mini","miny","moe"};
```

You access elements in an array using square brackets and the index of the object in the list you want to access. Arrays have a length property so you can easily count objects.

```
background(255);
String[] words = {"ini","mini","miny","moe"};
for(int i = 0 ; i < words.length; i++){
   fill(map(i,0,words.length, 0,255));
   text(words[i],10,10*(i+1));
}
```

Now back to your original question.
Here is your code using for loops and arrays:

```
int ballSize = 40;
int maxBalls = 100;//maximum number of balls on screen
int screenBalls = 0;//number of balls to update
int[] ballsX = new int[maxBalls];//initialize an empty list/array of x coordinates
int[] ballsY = new int[maxBalls];//...and y coordinates
void setup() {
  size(500, 400);
  fill(255, 0, 255);
}
void mouseClicked() {
  if (screenBalls < maxBalls) {//if still have room in our arrays for new ball coordinates
    ballsX[screenBalls] = mouseX;//add the current mouse coordinates(x,y)
    ballsY[screenBalls] = mouseY;//to the coordinate arrays at the current ball index
    screenBalls++;//increment the ball index
  }
}

void draw() {
  println(screenBalls);
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < screenBalls; i++) {//start counting from 0 to how many balls are on screen
    ballsX[i]++;//increment the x of each ball
    if(ballsX[i]-ballSize/2 > width) ballsX[i] = -ballSize/2;//if a ball goes off screen on the right, place it back on screen on the left
    ellipse(ballsX[i], ballsY[i], ballSize, ballSize);//display each ball
  }
}
```

There are multiple ways to tackle this. Arrays have fixed size. If you don't want to be constrained by that you can use an ArrayList (sort of a variable size array). Later you might want to look into how you can make an [object](http://processing.org/tutorials/objects/) that can update and draw itself. Have fun!